# What is an ABC Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an **ABC Word™**.
*Your mission, should you choose to accept*, is to find the rule that decides whether a word is an ABC Word™ or not, and why they are called so.

| ABC Word™ | Non-ABC Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| PYJAMAS | TROUSERS |
| TWEET | POST |
| FROLIC | WORK |
| VAMP | LADY |
| WHEN | HOW |
| COLORFUL | DRAB |
| SPASM | PEACEFUL |
| FULFIL | NEGLECT |
| TENT | HOUSE |
| GAMMA | ALPHA |

---

**CSV Version:**

```
ABC Word™,Non-ABC Word™
PYJAMAS,TROUSERS
TWEET,POST
FROLIC,WORK
VAMP,LADY
WHEN,HOW
COLORFUL,DRAB
SPASM,PEACEFUL
FULFIL,NEGLECT
TENT,HOUSE
GAMMA,ALPHA
```

**Hint:**

> Maybe assigning numbers to the letters will help you see a pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is:

> Assign each letter a number from 1-26: A=1, B=2 etc

Next we

> group letters that are equivalent modulo 3. Thus we have three groups ADGJMPSVY, BEHKNQTWZ, CFILORUX

An ABC word is

> any word using only letters from one group

Comment: Good show! That's correct! For more clarity behind the name, if you write the letters in a grid format with three columns, the top row reads `ABC`, and then the rule is that you make words from a single column.